# Pandas DataFrame: Calculate mean for those rows of one column which have same content of the second column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to ask if it is possible to calculate mean in pandas DataFrame the way I need it:

I have dataframe looking like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'rmsf': [1, 4, 7, 1, 5, 6, 4],
                   'residue': [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]})
df
```

And the result:

```
   rmsf residue
0   1     2
1   4     2
2   7     2
3   1     3
4   5     3
5   6     3
6   4     3
```

Now I'd like to calculate mean of "rmsf" values BUT only of those which belong to same "residue". So, I need mean for residue number 2,thus need to calculate mean of only first three rows of the column "rmsf" (1,4, and 7). Then for the residue number 3, I need to calculate mean from values 1,5,6, and 4, etc.
And the new means would be stored in a new dataframe looking like this:

```
   rmsf residue
0   4     2
1   8.5   3
```

Is there an approach how pandas can do it? Calculate mean of only those rows of one column which have same residue number in the second column?

Thank You.

Comment: Not sure how you calculated expected output, but it seems they are incorrect, tried to calculate manually and result comes as (4, 4) for both residue groups (2 & 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference by which column to group

Try this, but after don't forget to move columns

```
df.groupby('residue')['rmsf'].mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: I think reset_index is not needed and might be a bit confusing

Comment: @YannisP. sure it's not necessary, but without reset_index the output will be Series and I wanted DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

We tell pandas to:

1. Groupby the item you want `residue`
2. Select `rmsf`
3. Take its mean by group

```
df.groupby(['residue'])['rmsf'].agg('mean').reset_index()
```